# Why does appcmd.exe behave differently when executed inside a batch file?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, scripting, iis-7.5, batch-file

I have the following `appcmd` to add an exception to IIS7's ISAPI and CGI restrictions. The exception I am adding should look like:

`c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`

Here is the command line:

```
appcmd set config -section:isapiCgiRestriction "-+[path='c:\perl\bin\perl.exe \"%s\" %s', allowed='true', description='Perl CGI']"
```

If execute this from the command line it does this correctly, however if I execute this inside a `.cmd` batch file the path gets mangled and ends up looking like:

`c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "s`

The trouble seems arise because I have to escape the quotation marks around the first `%s` perl.exe parameter. But why this should behave differently in a batch file is a bit of a puzzle.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry to spam this over SO and SF....seems to fall into both sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows batch variables should be prefixed with an `%`, making these `%%s`

Comment: That fixes the batch file execution but breaks if executed from the command line. If run from command line I get `c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%%s" %%s` which breaks the ISAPI restriction because IIS expects `c:\perl\bin\perl.exe "%s" %s`. But because I'm solving this for task automation I can live with that. I'm guessing this has something to do with differences in the way that the command line processor handles variable expansion. Thanks for the speedy answer though.